# Dockerised React Nginx app not responding from VPS

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a dockerized react (deployed on port 5173) and backend Spring app (deployed on port 8080) with a nginx proxy. This is all working locally but not working on my virtual private server on GCP.

I have a DNS domain name which I am certain is set up properly.

When I go to my browser and enter the IP address of the VPS with the frontend port e.g. `XX.XXX.XX.XX:5173/about` nothing happens. I also tried to send a request to the backend e.g. `XX.XXX.XX.XX:8080/signup` nothing happens too.

I have checked the following:

1. No firewall issue on VPS:

```
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5173                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5173 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

2. Ports listing on VPS

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3307            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5173            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3307                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5173                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
upstream backend {
    server internet-speed-backend:8080;
  }

server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name MYDOMAIN.xyz wwww.MYDOMAIN.xyz;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  
  location @proxy-backend {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-db-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  internet-speed-backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server/Dockerfile
    container_name: backend-service-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  react-ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: client/Dockerfile
    container_name: react-service-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5173:80"
    depends_on:
    - internet-speed-backend
```